# What should I do when discovering plagiarism on the site?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I've noticed an answer (a few months old by now) on one network site, which copies essentially verbatim another answer to an SO question, without a reference nor credit.

So far, I've commented and downvoted, and put the reference in another answer, but I'm not sure: 1. Whether I've done the right thing and 2. What more, if anything, I should do.

I'll mention the plagiarized answer is the only answer and, in itself, is valid. It has a few upvotes.

Comment: Is it plagiarism or a cross-posted answer by the same author? If it's plagiarism it's probably worth a mod flag with explaination instead, after all... plagiarism is plagiarism

Comment: If it's a the same answer, by the same author, then they should have flagged the question as a dupe. if they've copied it from someone else, and it's not their work and they've not cited it, flag it as plagarism,

Comment: See [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/369403) on MSE